# Conditional rendering of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a component only if `asset.id === collection.masterAssetId`. If this is the case a star icon should appear. I am using the `getMasterId` function to check this condition. Anyone that knows what the error is here?

---

Error:

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token

  70 |                     
  71 |                     {
> 72 |                       if(asset.id === this.getMasterId(asset.id)){
     |                       ^
  73 |                       <FaStar />
  74 |                     }}
```

---

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {collections} from "./data.js"
import {assets} from "./data.js"
import {FontAwesome, FaStar} from "react-icons/fa"

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
           collectionsarr: collections,
           assetsarr: assets,
           clickedassets: []
        }
    }

    getMasterId(assetnr){
      const assetnum = this.state.collectionsarr.find(element => element.masterAssetId === assetnr).masterAssetId
      return assetnum
    }
  
  render(){
  return (
          <div className="App">
            <h1>Sitecore coding challenge</h1>
            
            <div className="left">
              {this.state.collectionsarr.map(element => 
                <div key={element.id}>
                  <p onClick={()=>this.handleAssetsClick(element.id)}>{element.name}</p>
                  <img src={this.getAssetPath(element.masterAssetId)} alt="pic"/>
                  <br></br>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>

            <div className="right">
                {this.state.clickedassets.map(asset => 
                  <div key={asset.id}>
                    <img src={require(`./${asset.path}`)} alt="pic"/>
                    <p>{asset.name}</p>
                    <p>{asset.id}</p>
                    <button onClick={() => this.makeMaster(asset.id)}>Make master!</button>
                    <p>icon "this is the master</p>
                    
                    {
                      if(asset.id === this.getMasterId(asset.id)){
                      <FaStar />
                    }}
                    
                    <br></br>
                  </div>
                )}
            </div>
          </div>
        )
  }
}
```

Comment: Try using the ternary operator `x ? y : z` instead of an if statement, or the conditional and operator `&&`

Comment: Did you search : ' conditional rendering React ' ? First result : https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: ok great now I am getting this: TypeError: Cannot read property 'masterAssetId' of undefined. Any idea why?

Comment: @charlesbxl well it means `element` is undefined. Which means there's a ' problem ' with your `collectionsarr` . Do you have elements in it ?

Comment: If you get solution from the answer please consider to mark it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the return code of the render function, you can only use expressions (things that are allowed on the right side of an equals). `if` is a statement, so it is not allowed. Example that **doesn't** work:

```js
const a = if(asset.id === this.getMasterId(asset.id)) return <FaStar />
```

However, a ternary expression is allowed. This would then look like this:

```js
const a = asset.id === this.getMasterId(asset.id) ? <FaStar /> : null
```

Comment: ok great now I am getting this: TypeError: Cannot read property 'masterAssetId' of undefined. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

Syntax you're using is wrong, Change it to

```
 { asset.id === this.getMasterId(asset.id) && <FaStar /> }
```

Read more about conditional rendering [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Comment: ok great now I am getting this: TypeError: Cannot read property 'masterAssetId' of undefined. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use statements in inline code within the return statement. You can only use expressions.

An if statement is a statement, so you should replace it with an expression such as the ternary operator `x ? y : z` or conditional and operator `&&`:

```
// ternary
asset.id === this.getMasterId(asset.id) ? <FaStar /> : null
```

or:

```
// conditional and
asset.id === this.getMasterId(asset.id) && <FaStar />
```

React has some great docs on [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

Be careful when using the conditional and `&&`, as if the first argument is the number `0` (for example, `list.length && <Component />`) then you will end up rendering a `0` instead of nothing.

In those cases it's best to cast to a Boolean:

```
Boolean(list.length) && <Component />
```

or:

```
!!list.length && <Component />
```

Comment: ok great now I am getting this: TypeError: Cannot read property 'masterAssetId' of undefined

Comment: `this.state.collectionsarr.find(element => element.masterAssetId === assetnr).masterAssetId`. `Array.find` will return `undefined` if nothing matches the condition. Make sure you check that the object exists before trying to access a property on it.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```html
(asset.id === this.getMasterId(asset.id)) ? <FaStar /> : <></>;
```

Comment: ok great now I am getting this: TypeError: Cannot read property 'masterAssetId' of undefined. Any idea why?